# Find Which Port Does SSH Client Used to Send Connection Request

Tags: linux, ssh

I am interested in finding out which port number the SSH client used to send connect/authentication request to server (default on port 22).

How can I discover it?

**SOLVED**

[image: For me client uses some arbitrary ports to connect]

Comment: During the connection setup? From a log file? From the server side or the client side?

Comment: From the client-side on at the time of connection setup, is there a way I can find out which port did SSH client used? I can guess it might be 80, but how can I be sure?

Comment: After connecting, you have `$SSH_CLIENT` which contains the client's IP, client's port, and the server's port. Do you imagine using a second terminal (or escaping out of the current ssh connection) to investigate the client port?

Comment: I am on `ubuntu 18.04`, unfortunately I do not see environment variable by name `SSH_CLIENT`. I grepped all environment variables for ssh `env | grep ssh` and the only environment variable I see is `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`

Comment: My comment addressed the remote end of the SSH connection; I wasn't sure where you were "looking" for the port information -- whether at the client-side or server-side (and within or without of the ssh connection itself).  From within the connection, after logging in, you'd have SSH_CLIENT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know what port a particular ssh connection will use, you can look in /etc/ssh/ssh_config for any system/global hosts configured, and in ~/.ssh/config for any user/local hosts.

If you want to know what port will be used by default, you can use the command `getent services ssh`. The standard is to connect to port 22.

If you want to know what ports are actively in use, the command `netstat --tcp --programs --numeric | grep ssh` should show you.

Comment: Won't the client use a high-numbered port to connect to the server's port 22?

Comment: @wyrm solution worked superfine. `Netstat` is what I was looking for. I observed that for each ssh connection client uses some arbitrary port number (I may be wrong but I do not see any patter). Client port (for me) lies in range like 53924, 53930 etc.